# MYSQ Workbench migrating a database

Tags: mysql

So I have a large database (85MB in size)  that I need to migrate from one web server to another.

I want to use Workbench to do this. However to connect to the mysql server I have to use SSH tunneling in the mysql workbench.

So my issue is that now then I click the Database Migration icon on the right side (under shortcuts) and try to use that feature I get an error stating that

"MYSQL Connection through SSH are not supported in this version of 
    the Mysql Workbench Migration Wizard"

I am using 6.3.8. Has anyone been able to figure out how to use mysql workbench to migrate a database using SSH tunneling. I have had great success migrating databases that do not require me to ssu tunnel within the Workbench.

Suggestions on how I might be able to move this database if not through Workbench

Comment: Most everyone here would not use this method but would probably use mysqldump.

Comment: Large is relative, but 85MB doesn't sound large compared to the bandwidth of any connection that you would run a webserver on. SSH in and mysqldump, scp copy it to the new server. If you can't, copy [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) (DB management tool in one PHP file) to the sites and use it to export the database, download the export, upload to the new site and import (example steps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432833/how-to-export-database-with-adminer )

Comment: You might find some additional methods by reading the [Mysql backup and recovery docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html) - although mysqldump sounds like it would do what you need.